# What is the suffix of "feature"?

Tags: suffixes

I am wondering what is the suffix of "feature". The wordinfo website
does not list the suffix for this word.

https://wordinfo.info/results?searchString=feature

But it lists "-ure" as the suffix of "rupture". Does it mean that the
"-ure" in "feature" should not be considered as a suffix as it doens't
denote "an act or result, result of the act of".

https://wordinfo.info/results?searchString=rupture

Comment: I'm not a definitive source, but as a native english speaker, I would not consider "feature" to be a word with a suffix at all.  "Rupture" has other related words like "erupt" which you can argue make "rupt" a prefix in "rupture", but I can't think of words related to "feature" in that way.

Comment: There is no English suffix on the English word _feature_. The _-ure_ ending comes from Latin, where it was part of a suffix when the word was borrowed, but is not a suffix in English. Latin grammar is not English grammar.

Answer (score 4):

English words ending with an apparent suffix [*-ure*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/-ure?ref=etymonline_crossreference), from Latin *-ura*, fall into two great classes: 1) those taken from Latin, directly or through French, where the suffix was present in one or both languages, and 2) those where the suffix was used to form new English words following the same pattern but without Latin/French originals.

[*Feature*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/feature#etymonline_v_1183), from Anglo-French *feture*, Old French *faiture*, ultimately from Latin *factura*, belongs to the first class along with many other words, such as [*manufacture*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/manufacture#etymonline_v_6833), [*departure*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/departure) or [*nomenclature*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/nomenclature#etymonline_v_9746).

Belonging to the second class are, for example, [*exposure*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/exposure), [erasure](https://www.etymonline.com/word/erasure), [seizure](https://www.etymonline.com/word/seizure#etymonline_v_23127), and [*expenditure*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/expenditure).

Comment: Can you elaborate on -ure as a native English suffix, that is how productive it is in English?

Comment: Someone dusted it off in 1869 to coin _photogravure_, so I suppose it's technically still productive. https://www.etymonline.com/word/photogravure#etymonline_v_50929